# AngularJS with Laravel 4 protect API calls from browser address bar

Tags: angularjs, laravel-4

im working on an existing Laravel 4 and AngularJS application. The routing is completely done by Angular. I use the $routeProvider and redirect if e.g. the user types in a not existing route in the browser address bar. This does work well. However, when I type something like 'website.com/api/users' the angular redirect does not work and I see the JSON response of the site. 
I already tried adding a Laravel filter which checks if the request is an ajax request:

```
if(Request::ajax()){
   return Redirect::to('/');
}
```

However, the expression does always validate to false. I would not want any user, logged in or not, to make such API calls via the browser address bar. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What specific higher level problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSON Web Token would help you if you want to protect your API from public access. 
Link : https://jwt.io/
Using routes to secure your APIs is not a good practice and will always lead to vulnerabilities.

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look at it.